# Can I use the SSH vi code editor with phpseclib?

Tags: php, ssh, vi, phpseclib

Hey I am wondering if I can use the vi code editor while connected with phpseclibs SSH2. My goal is to be able to run a PHP script and update values of a config file. I can connect via SSH just fine, but nothing I enter into the script afterwords seems to be changing anything in the targeted config file.
This is what I have so far.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

//simulate pressing the escape key
$esc = chr(27);

$ssh = new SSH2('ip address');
if(!ssh->login('username', 'password')){
    exit('Login Failed');
}

sleep(5);
//enter vi editor
$ssh->write("vi file address\n");
sleep(5);
//"/"enables seach mode in vi editor
$ssh->write("/seachword\n");
sleep(1);
//clears line in vi editor
$ssh->write("cc");
sleep(1);
//enter in new word on that empty line
$ssh->write("replacement word");
sleep(1);
//simulates pressing the esc key
$ssh->write("$esc");
sleep(1);
//saves and closes the vi editor
$ssh->write(":wq\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use `vi` with phpseclib but I'd really recommend against it. For scriptable stuff you'd really be better off using [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk).

That said, it is none-the-less possible, as the following demonstrates:

```
function waitForVertical($ssh)
{
    $output = $ssh->read(
        '#' .
            "\x1B\[\d+C" . // move cursor right n lines
            "(?:All|Top|\d\d%|Bot)" .
            "\x1B\[\d+;\d+H" . // move cursor to screen location v,h
        '#',
        SSH2::READ_REGEX
    );
    if ($ssh->isTimeout()) {
        throw new \Exception('Timeout');
    }
}

function waitForHorizontal($ssh)
{
    $output = $ssh->read(
        '#' .
            "\x1B\[\d+;\d+H" . // move cursor to screen location v,h
            "\d+" .
            "\x1B\[\d+;\d+H" . // move cursor to screen location v,h
        '#',
        SSH2::READ_REGEX
    );
    if ($ssh->isTimeout()) {
        throw new \Exception('Timeout');
    }
}

$ssh = new SSH2('127.0.0.1', 2222);
if(!$ssh->login('vagrant', 'vagrant')){
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$start = microtime(true);

$ssh->read('vagrant@vagrant:~$');
// enter vi editor
$ssh->write("vi file address\n");
waitForVertical($ssh);
// "/"enables seach mode in vi editor
$ssh->write("/seachword\n");
waitForVertical($ssh);
// clears line in vi editor
$ssh->write('cc');
waitForVertical($ssh);
// enter in new word on that empty line
$ssh->write('replacement word');
waitForHorizontal($ssh);
// hit escape button
$ssh->write("\x1B");
waitForVertical($ssh);
// saves and closes the vi editor
$ssh->write(":wq\n");
$ssh->read('vagrant@vagrant:~$');

$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "took $elapsed seconds\n";
```

Note how I'm not using `sleep` whereas you are. In theory I think it's better to wait for specific output then it is to just `sleep`. Of course, even then, who's to say if all versions of `vi` will return ANSI escape codes that are used to build out the UI in the same order.

Also, it is strange that you're opening two files with `vi` instead of just one...

Comment: Hey, just to clarify i'm only opening one .cfg file after logging in via SSH. I tried your solution and I am getting timeout exceptions on all WaitForVertical() and WaitForHorizontal() function calls. I basically copy pasted your code and replaced username/password/ip address/file location and the text being searched for and replacement text in the file. You mentioned not to use the vi editor here, what would be another option for changing .cfg file data via phpseclib?

Comment: Could we DM about this?  I Can give you more info on the details that way. As the details are sensitive and I am not permitted to post them here.

Comment: @Dagroa - I'd recommend using `sed` or `awk`. If you pursue that route I'd post on stackoverflow or superuser for questions you might have about those tools. Just as an issue with jQuery isn't necessarily an issue with Google Chrome an issue with sed isn't necessarily an issue with phpseclib. That said, if you do want to share sensitive info email terrafrost@php.net and be sure to include a link to this stackoverflow post for context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using sed for editing the config file, and it works great, thanks neubert. here is what I am using.

```
$ssh = new SSH2('IP');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec("sed -i -e 's/text to find/replacement text/g' /path/and/name");
```